# How can I prevent onBlur event from firing?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to build an input with a dropdown that provides suggestions. I have an input element that uses onBlur, which technically when click outside will remove the ul element. When I click on the ul element, it also removes the ul element, which fires the onBlur event on the input. Is there a way to implement onBlur that prevents the ul element to fire the onBlur event?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import "./styles.css";

const Autocomplete = (props) => {
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState("");

  const [listResults, setListResults] = useState([]);

  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filteredResults = props.options.filter((option) =>
      option.includes(userInput)
    );

    setListResults(filteredResults);
  }, [userInput, props.options]);

  const handleInput = (event) => {
    setUserInput(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleInputClick = () => {
    setOpenModal(!openModal);
  };

  const handleClickOption = (data) => {
    setUserInput(data);
    setOpenModal(false);
    ulEl.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <input
        name="search-input"
        value={userInput}
        onChange={handleInput}
        autoComplete="off"
        onFocus={handleInputClick}
        onBlur={handleInputClick}
      />
      <ul className="search-list">
        {openModal &&
          listResults &&
          listResults.map((data, key) => (
            <li
              key={key}
              onClick={() => {
                handleClickOption(data);
              }}
            >
              {data}
            </li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Autocomplete;
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Short answer, just add this to your element

```
onMouseDown={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
```

In this situation, call `event.preventDefault()` on the `onMouseDown` event. `onMouseDown` will cause a blur event by default, and will not do so when `preventDefault` is called. Then, `onClick` will have a chance to be called. A blur event will still happen, only after `onClick`.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you! I found another solution where I can have the onClick function to be onMouseDown instead since onBlur happens right after the onMouseDown event.

Answer (score -2):

You may use the [list](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_list.asp) attribute of `<input>` with a `<datalist>` instead of using a `<ul>`.

Hope this suits your case.